# Modify brightness hotkeys behavior

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, brightness

The Debian sid install on my Lenovo T450 allows control over the brightness via `fn+F5` and `fn+F6` keys.

In dark environments, the minimum brightness setting is too dim for me, however min brightness + 1, is too bright.

The file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` allows me to read the current brightness setting, and using `echo 16 > brightness`, i can set my ideal brightness.

Min brightness = 1
Max brightness = 851

I've also found that setting brightness to zero appers to disable the backlight entirely.

Is there a way to somehow configure brightness hotkey behavior in Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

Set a custom shortcut:
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en

Use `xbacklight`:

$ `xbacklight -inc 10`

$ `xbacklight -dec 10`

Comment: Extra note: `intel_backlight` is sometimes buggy with `xbacklight`.  I may be needed to set `Option "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"` inside the `Device` section of xorg.conf